# Como usar o virtualenv do Python no Windows

Tags: python

Após instalado com sucesso o `virtualenv` com o comando:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Quando vou criar uma virtualenv com o comando

```
virtualenv -p python3 coleta_dados
```

Ele me traz o seguinte

'virtualenv' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

O que falta fazer?

Estou usando o python 3.10.2

Comment: python -m venv minhavenv

Comment: Deu certo! :) Adiciona a resposta por favor.. Faço questão de votar

Comment: Um detalhe importante em relação à resposta aceita: `venv` e `virtualenv` são coisas diferentes - o primeiro vem junto da biblioteca padrão de Python, o segundo é um pacote externo que se instala com `pip`. Ambos servem pra mesma coisa mas apresentam funcionamento distinto. [Essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573588/11161432) (do SO em inglês) se aprofunda na diferença entre essas e outras ferramentas de gerenciamento de ambientes virtuais de Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criação da venv você deve "chamar" o python, o comando da venv e depois nomea-la, conforme abaixo:

```
python -m venv minhavenv
```

Answer (score -2):

No caso a criação de uma virtualenv não precisa chamar python.
Depois de instalar a virtualenv o comando que você precisa dar é:

```
virtualenv nomedavirtualenv
```

Para ativar a virtualenv criada você precisa acessar o arquivo activate da virtualenv com o seguinte comando (estando no diretório que ela foi criada):

```
nomedavirtualenv\Scripts\activate
```

Note que a resposta mais votada acima cria uma venv, que não é a virtualenv, são ferramentas de gerenciamento de ambientes diferentes.